# How do I include computername in output

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query

PS newbe here...

How do I get the remote computer name to appear in the output?

```
$computer = "PC3090-121","APCD02" 
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $computer |
  Select-Object SystemName,Name,Local |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I've tried including -computername, computername, %computername% in the Select and format-table -properties - no joy...

My searches have come up empty, or I couldn't understand them.

------------------------------ answer:

```
$computer = "PC3090-121","APCD02" 
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $computer |
  Select-Object  __Server, Name, Local |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about simply

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $computer |
  Select-Object SystemName,Name,Local |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```

There is no `computername` property on the resulting object, nor is there a `%computername%` property. What exists is `SystemName`.

Comment: SystemName returns the name of the host for the printer/print service. If the remote PC uses a print server the name of the print server host is returned.

Comment: `__SERVER` then, maybe. Otherwise you could just wrap a loop around the call: `foreach ($c in $computer) { gwmi Win32_printer -computername $c | select @{l='ComputerName';e={$c}},Name,Local }` or something like that.

Comment: You can inspect objects with all their properties (and values) by using `Format-List -Force *` or (`fl -fo *`). This is often helpful in finding which properties you need to select.

Comment: @Joey  can we use $Env:ComputerName variable?