# Inventory of MSKB Patch Updates already installed using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, remote-server

I have tried PowerShell's `Get-Hotfix` and do not like the results. I do not need to install any new updates. I would like to get the results in a CSV format as I have about 30 servers to list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$servern = 'ABC'

$Session =  [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$servern))
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$Searcher.QueryHistory(1, $historyCount) | Select-Object Date,$servern,
$temp = "" | Select Computer, operation, resultcode,resultcode 

$temp.Computer = $servern,
$temp.operation = expression={switch($_.operation){
    1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}},
$temp.resultcode = expression={switch($_.resultcode){
        1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"};
        4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}
}}
$temp.Title

# What we would like to see is:
# SERVER, DATE, TITLE, OPERATION, RESULTCODE
# ABC,5/5/2011 3:29:52 PM,Update for Windows Server 2003 (KB927891),Installation,Succeeded
# ABC,5/5/2011 3:30:01 PM,Cumulative Security Update for Outlook Express for Windows Server 2003 (KB929123),Installation,Succeeded
# etc..
```

And to have these results in a CSV.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer for you, but are you using WSUS? If so, can you use the WSUS cmdlets that are available in WSUS 4/PowerShell 3? This way WSUS would keep track of all of this for you and you could query it in a central location.

Comment: I don't know if it is WSUS or Shavlik or?  The updates to our servers are managed by a different group than ours.  We are independently trying to capture a log or list of servers/patches installed and then address with the patching team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have and this works great!

Thanks to a posting that is in comments from "StuStars" at
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4197.how-to-list-all-of-the-windows-and-software-updates-applied-to-a-computer.aspx

Other resources used:

- [How do I include computername in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640660/how-do-i-include-computername-in-output)
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/81d0b3f6-c8db-4e4d-9676-9fcdef6dea25/help-with-exportcsv-append

Also, thanks for the split routine from [Boe Prox](http://learn-powershell.net/2011/03/07/find-pending-updates-on-local-or-remote-computers/) to separate out the KB Article. This will list out the updates locally.

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Date,
   @{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){
       1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}}},
   @{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){
       1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"};
       4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}
}}},
   @{n='KB';e={(($_.Title -split('\('))[1] -split('\)'))[0] }},
   Title
 | Export-Csv -NoType "$Env:userprofile\Desktop\Windows Updates.csv"
```

And places a file on your desktop called: `Windows Updates.csv`.

Let's re-work this a bit. We are going to assume that you have access to the set of servers and you can run scripts to query them. Now, let's place a filter on this. This uses a list of servers (`Named_computers.txt`) with a name, for example:

```
ABC
DEF
```

Code is:

```
$results = @()
$serverlist = "D:\WORK\ps\Named_computers.txt"

foreach ($computer in Get-Content $serverlist) {
    $Session =  [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$computer))
    $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
    $results += $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Date,
        @{n='ComputerName';e={$computer}},
        @{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){
            1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}}},
        @{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){
            1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"};
            4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}
        }}},
        @{n='KB';e={(($_.Title -split('\('))[1] -split('\)'))[0] }},
        Title
        }
$results |
where { $_.Date -gt "01/01/2014"} |
Export-Csv -NoType "$Env:userprofile\Desktop\Windows Updates.csv"
```

Let's change it up a bit and provide a couple filters that I used over the weekend. This uses a list of servers (`Monitored_computers.txt) with a Name and IP address, for example:

```
ABC,1.1.1.1
DEF,2.2.2.2
```

Code is:

```
$results = @()
$serverlist = "D:\WORK\ps\monitored_computers.txt"

foreach ($computer in Get-Content $serverlist) {
$servern=$computer.split(",")[0]
$ip=$computer.split(",")[1]

    $Session =  [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$servern))
    $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
    $results += $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Date,
        @{n='ComputerName';e={$servern}},
        @{n='IP';e={$ip}},
        @{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){
            1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}}},
        @{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){
            1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"};
            4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}
        }}},
        @{n='KB';e={(($_.Title -split('\('))[1] -split('\)'))[0] }},
        Title
        }
$results |
#where { $_.Date -gt "01/01/2014" } |
where { $_.Date -gt "01/01/2014" -and  $_.Status -ne "Succeeded" } |
Export-Csv -NoType "$Env:userprofile\Desktop\Windows Updates.csv"
```